# swift parse facebook error: PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, initialization

I've been having some issues with Parses FaceBook integration lately.
This is the error I'm stuck with now:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',                       reason: '-[PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider authType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c1bd410'

This is my code that causes the error:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool  {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent



    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {

        let types:UIUserNotificationType = (.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    } else {

        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
    }

    if let options = launchOptions {

        if let notification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {



        }

    }
    // parse
    Parse.setApplicationId("ieTrfDHsgFjTKNHBNxxJtLM90zPyFGkSAt9SFYpg", clientKey: "AB9zJolZfSJvjv34idumNoksPC6Qux9KovKB0pnu")
    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    } else {
 // this causes the error  
              PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions([NSObject:AnyObject]())
    }


    return true

}
```

I hope you can help.
Thanks

Comment: It seems that the code that causes this error is somewhere else. Can you provide the snippet around the code where you call [PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider authType] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did add the newest parse framework, but not the newest bolts framework. Adding that solved the problem.